# about windows metro threading model

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Can someone explain the threading model in windows metro?
I really get confusion about this.

I know that the WWAHost.exe creates the first MTA (main thread?)
and we also have a UI thread(STA?) and some worker thread(STAorMTA?)

and only the main thread can update to UI thread.
So when user touch a button , and then what happened?
sry, my english is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little about it in the [CoreApplication class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.aspx) text:

> The system creates this object as a singleton when it runs the app. It
>   is run as an Application Single-Threaded Apartment (ASTA). Threads
>   created from the app singleton, such as the view provider (seen in the
>   sample below), should be attributed as Multi-Threaded Apartment
>   (MTAThread).